# Retrieving data from mlab heroku

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

I followed a tutorial to learn Express.js App that performs basic CRUD operations from MongoDB. All operations created locally works fine.
As a next step (not in the tutorial), I needed to integrate mLab provided by Heroku for MongoDB in order to push the app to Heroku.

Now, I need to make necessary changes on the mongoose connection since I am moving from a local database to mLab. I made necessary changes but now the app throws an error.

complaintController.js (class to get request and use the model)

```
Complaint = require('./complaintModel');
exports.index = function (req, res) {
Complaint.get(function (err, complaints) {      //GET function
    if (err) {
        res.json({
            status: "error",
            message: err,
        });
    }
    res.json({
        status: 200,
        message: "Complaints retrieved successfully",
        data: complaints
    });
});
};
```

complaintModel.js (**local MongoDB this works fine**)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var complaintSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
});


 // Export Complaint model

 var Complaint = module.exports = mongoose.model('complaint', complaintSchema);
 module.exports.get = function (callback, limit) {
     Complaint.find(callback).limit(limit);
 }
```

complaintModel.js ( **connecting to mLab throws error**)

```
var mongoDB = "MongoDB URI";

var connection = mongoose.createConnection(mongoDB,
{    
  User: 'username',
  Password: 'pass'
});

var Complaint;
connection.on('open', function() {
  console.log('connection established!!!');
  Complaint = module.exports = connection.model('master_complaint', complaintSchema);
  module.exports.get = function (callback, limit) {
    Complaint.find(callback).limit(limit);
  }
});
```

Here I get the following error when I give a get request I understood there is an export issue of Complaint Module but any suggestion or idea will be helpful.

```
TypeError: Complaint.get is not a function
at exports.index (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\controller\complaintController.js:6:15)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at jsonParser (R:\Workings\PersWork\web\webpack-demo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the code. **complaintController** will be used by the express.js router, Am I correct?

I also see in the **complaintModel.js** is that the get function you've exported requires 2 parameters which are a filter & a limit. But in the **Controller file** you're not providing any of those arguments at all.

I haven't tested this myself yet but try changing your **complaintModel.js** to this

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var complaintSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

var Complaint = mongoose.model("master_complaint", complaintSchema);

// Exports the get function
module.exports.get = function(filter, limit, callback) {
  var mongoDB = "MongoDB URI";

  var connection = mongoose.createConnection(mongoDB, {
    User: "username",
    Password: "pass"
  });

  connection.on("open", function() {
    console.log("connection established!!!");

    Complaint.find(filter)
      .limit(limit)
      .exec()
      .then(results => {
          callback(undefined, results)
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          callback("ERROR: Can't query the collection", undefined)
      });
  });
};
```

And change the **complaintController.js** to the following

```
var Complaint = require("./complaintModel");

module.exports.index = function(req, res) {
  var params = req.query;
  const filter = params.filter;
  const limit = params.limit;

  Complaint.get(
    filter,
    limit,
    (err,
    complaints => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          status: "error",
          message: err
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          status: 200,
          message: "Complaints retrieved successfully",
          data: complaints
        });
      }
    })
  );
};
```